# How do I use PHP to apply css properties?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to use PHP to link a CSS document's properties to itself much like this HTML would:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css">
```

To be specific, I don't want to import the CSS file so that it simply displays in between two CSS `<style>` tags in my HTML. I want the PHP to apply the  properties from the CSS document.

I also want the PHP to be able to work in this if statement:

```
<?php
if ($mobile == True)
{
//Your solution here
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why would you want to do that? And to what do you want to apply CSS properties?

Comment: What you want is basically really simple, just include your php file in the link tag and send the proper headers. But it'd be way simpler to just apply a "mobile" class and modify the CSS accordingly. Imho you should join us in 2014 and read about [Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/).

Comment: @kapa I want to apply the CSS properties to the HTML in the PHP document. I want to do this because I have a very light, fast & intelligent PHP query which senses if the browser is mobile. This PHP query won't be anywhere near as fast or accurate with something else.

Comment: @LarryK I understand that your PHP query or whatever really rocks and stuff... but... why is it not good enough to include a mobile-specific stylesheet when this amazing PHP query shouts "Mobile!"? Why do you want inline styles?

Comment: @nietonfir I already use percentage units for most of my CSS properties, but the way I want my mobile site to look is quite a bit different and therefore calls for some very different CSS properties.

Comment: @kapa How do I do that? Right now I have this: 
`<!--mobile styles--> <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 900px)" href="mobile.css" /> <!--android--> <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="mobile.css" />` and I'm not using any PHP, but like I told @veritascs, oftentimes this doesn't work on android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're asking for, but it isn't best practice and I wouldn't recommend it. I would refer you to @nietonfir's suggestion (despite being a little harsh, he/she is right). Doing mobile stuff in CSS as a part of a responsive design (media queries) is soooooo much better and easier.

```
<?php
if ($mobile == True){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot! Why didn't I think of that‽ Thanks! I would vote up your response if I could!

Comment: Well, everyone is an idiot at some point, which is why everyone else tries to help. In fact, even the programmers who have been doing it for 10+ years are still learning. I try to idiot through things as fast as possible, which helps. Stack Overflow's tagline should be  "Helping you be less of an idiot every day."

Comment: While it is easier, let's not forget the flipside to that suggestion: increased download time. If I'm visiting from an iPhone, it'll be downloading all this unnecesary desktop-only css, even though I'll never use it. On the other hand, we're talking about a lot of work for (what is usually) a minimal in saved download time. I'm just saying weigh your options and pick the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Definitely @DanielRippstein I agree, but I also think there is value in seeing the other method so you learn what not to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to put an specific css file into the html?
This is not the correct aproach, since w3c already have this [problem fixed](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/mobilweb)

But what you want to do is put direct css into the html... is like printing the code with `echo`

```
<?php
if ($mobile == True)
{
    echo '<style type="text/css">
              /*
               * your mobile css
               */

               body{
                   color: #f00;
                   background: #000;
               }
          </style>';
}
?>
```

Wich is something i REALLY DO NOT RECOMMEND

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct. Assuming you are trying to apply certain styles for mobile devices you can use media queries in your CSS. 
See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Or if you are just trying to set styles based on the screen width:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* your styles here.... */
}
```

Comment: What I have right now for mobile browser detection is:
`<!--mobile styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 900px)" href="mobile.css" />
<!--android-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="mobile.css" />`
  
But oftentimes this doesn't work on android devices. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: It probably isn't working sometimes because you are specifying the screen density. See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#DensityCSS) for more. Checkout bootstrap or foundation and see how they build their responsive frameworks. Their styles, including media queries, don't care what device it is, just screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to load a different css for a mobile view. Due to, my prefered way is to have one css file within modifications for different views. So, in your **style.css** you can do following:

```
.example-box { width: 1200px; background-color: #ccc; }

/* Tablet Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .example-box { width: 1000px; background-color: #ccc; }
}

/* Smaller than 960px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .example-box { width: 900px; background-color: #ccc; }
}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .example-box { width: 900px; background-color: #ccc; }
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .example-box { width: 700px; background-color: #ccc; }
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .example-box { width: 700px; background-color: #ccc; }
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .example-box { width: 400px; background-color: #ccc; }
}
```